# Incoming Mails are not working on my CWP Mail server

Tags: server, centos7, postfix-mta, cwp

[amavis and spamassassin not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAizA.png)

[amavis log[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubyOJ.png)

Comment: Please share more details - is this even related to programming?